# Turn Off JQuery UI tooltip and need to used regular tooltip within a page

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

I have JQuery in  my application. But I want to Turn Off Jquery script for tool tip and want to use regular tool tip in  tag

I followed this document and tried disable, hide all properties. Its hiding and  whole `<a>` element https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Plese find myJSFiddler here: [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/n1rjbgmk/3/)

```
  $(function () {
      $(document).tooltip({
          content: function () {
              return $(this).prop('title');
          }
      });
  });
```

Please let me know how can I get regular Tooltip instead of styling tooltip

Comment: If you do not assign ToolTip, it will not initialize. If you want to initialize it, but also disable it, you can use the `disable` method: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0w278gLj/4/ And https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-disable

Comment: Thanks Twisty for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not assign ToolTip, it will not initialize.

If you want to initialize it, but also disable it, you can use the disable method: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0w278gLj/4

```
$(function() {
  //$("body").tooltip().tooltip("disable");
});
```

See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-disable